# Pacemaker cloned resource stickiness

Tags: pacemaker

I have set up a small cluster of three nodes. I've created an IPaddr2 (or IPaddr3 from Percona) VIP and it came up ok. Initially, I have following distribution:

```
Full List of Resources:
  * Clone Set: ClusterIP-clone [ClusterIP] (unique):
    * ClusterIP:0       (ocf::percona:IPaddr3):  Started node1
    * ClusterIP:1       (ocf::percona:IPaddr3):  Started node2
    * ClusterIP:2       (ocf::percona:IPaddr3):  Started node3
```

Then I restart node2, pacemaker picks that up and assigns traffic for node2 to node1, so distribution changes to:

```
Full List of Resources:
  * Clone Set: ClusterIP-clone [ClusterIP] (unique):
    * ClusterIP:0       (ocf::percona:IPaddr3):  Started node1
    * ClusterIP:1       (ocf::percona:IPaddr3):  Started node1
    * ClusterIP:2       (ocf::percona:IPaddr3):  Started node3
```

Now, as node2 comes back up nothing happens due to resource-stickiness=1 for cloned resources. But if I then set resource-stickiness=0 for my ClusterIP, distribution changes to this:

```
Full List of Resources:
  * Clone Set: ClusterIP-clone [ClusterIP] (unique):
    * ClusterIP:0       (ocf::percona:IPaddr3):  Started node2
    * ClusterIP:1       (ocf::percona:IPaddr3):  Started node1
    * ClusterIP:2       (ocf::percona:IPaddr3):  Started node3
```

So now instead of having 'node1, node2, node3' I have 'node2, node1, node3' and this causes all the customers to disconnect from underlaying servers as now node2 is not serving IP packets destined for the second group of customers but instead it serves first group of customers. This causes TCP disconnects and then reconnects.

Is there a way to specify that ClusterIP:0 should prefer node1, ClusterIP:1 should prefer node2, ClusterIP:2 should prefer node 3? As this is a cloned resource I haven't found a way to achieve this. Thanks.